# java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information

Tags: java, postgresql, caching, redis, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing Spring Data with Redis cache, MySQL, JPA Hibernate CRUD API . Caching is not working for controllers I used and not reflecting but for GetMapping and PostMapping it's working because I am not using any cache configuration, but the other three controllers which I configured with cache, I get connection refused. I didn't install any Redis cache in local. Is it required to install Redis cache for this because I'm using Redis for cache.

**Controller**

```
package com.example.redis.springbootrediscache.controller;

import com.example.redis.springbootrediscache.ResouceNotFoundException;
import com.example.redis.springbootrediscache.model.Employee;
import com.example.redis.springbootrediscache.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CachePut;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EmployeeController {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;

    @PostMapping("/employees")
    public Employee addEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {

        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }

    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Employee>> getAllEmployees() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeRepository.findAll());
    }

    @GetMapping("employees/{employeeId}")
    @Cacheable(value = "employees",key = "#employeeId")
    public Employee findEmployeeById(@PathVariable(value = "employeeId") Integer employeeId) {
        System.out.println("Employee fetching from database:: "+employeeId);
        return employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResouceNotFoundException("Employee not found" + employeeId));
    }

    @PutMapping("employees/{employeeId}")
    @CachePut(value = "employees",key = "#employeeId")
    public Employee updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "employeeId") Integer employeeId,
                                                   @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResouceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id :: " + employeeId));
        employee.setName(employeeDetails.getName());
        final Employee updatedEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);
        return updatedEmployee;
    }

    @DeleteMapping("employees/{id}")
    @CacheEvict(value = "employees", allEntries = true)
    public void deleteEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Integer employeeId) {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId).orElseThrow(
                () -> new ResouceNotFoundException("Employee not found" + employeeId));
        employeeRepository.delete(employee);
    }
}
```

**Employee**

```
package com.example.redis.springbootrediscache.model;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class Employee implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String name;

}
```

**SpringBootApplication**

```
package com.example.redis.springbootrediscache;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.EnableCaching;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class SpringbootRedisCacheApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootRedisCacheApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**application.yaml**

```yaml
spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
    redis:
      time-to-live: 60000
      cache-null-values: true
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/TradeX
    username: postgres
    password: admin
    hikari:
      initialization-fail-timeout: 0
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    generate-ddl: true
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create


server:
  port: 8087
```

**pom.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example.redis</groupId>
    <artifactId>springboot-redis-cache</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>springboot-redis-cache</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.5.0</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: If you want to use Redis for caching, you need to have a Redis instance up-and-running, and the correct host and port configured in your Spring Boot application (Spring Boot by default assumes localhost, port 6379).

Comment: I got it thanks, Unable to configure the port number of Redis. I didn't install Redis locally.